# What does this nonprinting symbol mean in Microsoft Word?

Tags: icons, gui, editing, microsoft-word-2011, symbols

I have a document from another editor that includes a non-printing character (it goes away when paragraph icon in ribbon is toggled) that I do not recognize:

[image]

I don't know how to search for an image, so I searched Google for things like `microsoft word non printing characters legend` and found pages like [this one](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/NonPrintChars.htm), but none showed this unusual symbol that I've never come across before, so it must be obscure.  What does the rectangular shaped symbol to the left of the two spaces and paragraph symbols mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a **no width non-break**

I've found it here: http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/NonprintChars.htm

---

> Beginning in Word 2000, Microsoft added two new special characters to
>   Word: the no-width optional break and the no-width non break. ....
>   These characters were intended for use with some Asian languages,
>   where characters can be placed beside or on top of one another. Also,
>   the languages may use syntactic constructions that have no spaces
>   between sequential words, unlike the English language which uses
>   spaces to separate words.

from [here](http://word.tips.net/T003882_Understanding_the_No-Width_Characters.html).