# What is Word's non-printing symbol that is a small circle (looks like a "degrees" mark)?

Tags: windows-10, gmail, microsoft-word-2013, special-characters, characters

What is Word's non-printing symbol that is a small circle (looks like a "degrees" mark)? I haven't found this in other articles, web searches, forums. Is it a new version of "keep with next"?

This comes up regularly when copy/pasting from a gmail draft into Word for the purpose of fixing formatting (gmail often scrambles my formatting even if it looks right before I hit send).

These are helpful but still don't contain the mark I'm looking for:
http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/NonprintChars.htm
http://wordribbon.tips.net/T005994_Understanding_Nonprinting_Characters.html
[What does this nonprinting symbol mean in Microsoft Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1050823/what-does-this-nonprinting-symbol-mean-in-microsoft-word)

Here's how it looks like :

[image]

Comment: Screenshot please. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 8):

#### What is the nonprinting symbol that is a small circle (looks like a "degrees" mark)?

It's a **non-breaking space**.

---

#### Space Characters

> A degree symbol ° represents a non-breaking space (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), which you can use to prevent words from being separated at the end of a line.

Source [Nonprinting Formatting Marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm)

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of MS Word, and other Office tools, there is a new feature that looks just like a degree mark that appears under the cursor.  Searching for what this may be provides this question as a possible answer, especially since it also appears when using copying and pasting or other document repositioning.

There is a feature that is related to MS Word's touch features.

It will appear if you scroll the screen around, and pause for a moment, or if you touch the screen to position the cursor, or to select a section of text.

To use this feature, start off by tapping the screen once to position the cursor at that location.  You can then move the cursor by dragging the circle to another location.  If you want to select text, double click on text and it will select that word, then you can drag the starting position or the ending position.

You cannot select it with the mouse, but if you have a touch screen, you can use touch to reposition the selections.

[Word's touch feature when positioning the cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7tX.png)

[Word's touch feature when selecting multiple characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIIWS.png)

More information [About the Word's Touch features](https://office-watch.com/2021/microsoft-office-touch-screen-options/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).